# Mobile website doesn't work on IOS 11+

Tags: ios, css, iphone, ios11

I have a problem with new version of IOS, it doesn't even open on IPhone with the latest OS. It says "website crashed"and empty page. It works on old versions. Actually I made special css only for Iphone and

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

@supports (-webkit-marquee-repetition:infinite) and (object-fit:fill) {
        @supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
 body {
      overflow-y: scroll;
      height: 1700px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      position: relative;
      background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center , #0c505f, 
      #053540);
      color: #0c505f;
      width: 95vw;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be simply a permission issue,

Please check your PList file

Add this

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

or

```
NSAppTransportSecurity - 
  - NSAllowsArbitraryLoads - Yes
```

Comment: Actually, I am using Windows not Mac IOS and I think I don't have this PList in my files, can you suggest me where I can put this code for permission?

Comment: @AlinaBayron Please provide more details of your Development environment like IDE etc. if possible screenshoots

Comment: It's not an application, it's responsive website with javascript. I am using NotePad and Netbeans.  I have just simple index.html style.css and javascript file